# Create own date mappings in API.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to create a mapping of date ranges and what a user says.
For example:

- When a user says "**MTD** sales for Product A", I want the bot to understand that **MTD means current month start to today** (Date-Period format). How can I do this?
- Also, the agent is able to understand **first half of last month** (15 day range) but cannot understand "**first 15 days of last month**". How can I map this statement to a date range so that it learns similar examples for the future?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create an entity for date-period formats with the list of formats you want to support?

Then the selected format could be sent to your custom webhook configured in fullfillment. You would receive this format as a parameter in your backend and could do anything you want with this information.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But the problem is that I already have a lot combinations to handle in webhook.
It would have been great if somehow I could map it to the Date-Period system variable. Like when the user says MTD then it means period as Current Month Start / Today.